# R: Calculating offset differences between elements in data frame with the same identifier

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is a subset of my data:

```
> head(dt)

   name    start     end
1:    1  3195984 3197398
2:    1  3203519 3205713
3:    2  3204562 3207049
4:    2  3411782 3411982 
5:    2  3660632 3661579
6:    3  3638391 3640590

dt <- data.frame(name = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3), start = c(3195984, 
3203519, 3204562, 3411782, 3660632, 3638391), end = c(3197398, 
3205713, 3207049, 3411982, 3661579, 3640590))
```

I want to calculate another value: the difference between the end coordinate of line n and the start coordinate of line n+1 but only if both elements share a name. To elaborate this is what I want a resulting data frame to look like:

```
   name    start     end    dist
1:    1  3195984 3197398
2:    1  3203519 3205713   -6121
3:    2  3204562 3207049
4:    2  3411782 3411982 −204733
5:    2  3660632 3661579 −248650
6:    3  3638391 3640590
```

The reason I want to do this is that I'm looking for dist values that are positive. One way I've tried this is to offset the start and end coordinates but then I run into a problem where I am comparing things with different names.

How does one do this in R?

Comment: Is that a `data.table` rather than a `data.frame`? It looks like it from the way the row names are printing. If so, that opens up some other options for answers.

Comment: @thelatemail `> class(dt)` gives: `[1] "data.frame"`. Would it be best to try to convert to a `data.table`?

Comment: No, not necessarily, they are just slightly different in terms of possible solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `data.table` solution may be good here:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(dt)
dt[, dist := c(NA, end[-(length(end))] - start[-1]) , by=name]
dt

#   name   start     end    dist
#1:    1 3195984 3197398      NA
#2:    1 3203519 3205713   -6121
#3:    2 3204562 3207049      NA
#4:    2 3411782 3411982 -204733
#5:    2 3660632 3661579 -248650
#6:    3 3638391 3640590      NA
```

Assuming your data is sorted, you can also do it with base R functions:

```
dt$dist <- unlist(
  by(dt, dt$name, function(x) c(NA, x$end[-(length(x$end))] - x$start[-1]) )
)
```

Comment: I'm getting a `non-numeric argument to binary operator` using this code. So my start and end are considered as factors, I think. Would the correct way to fix this be to use `length(as.numeric(as.character(end)))` in the code?

Comment: If you have numeric data that is being stored as a factor, then I would make it numeric to start with before doing further calculations: `dat$start <- as.numeric(as.character(dat$start))` etc. Be careful about what data you are throwing away with this conversion though.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr (with credit to @thelatemail for the calculation of dist):

```
library(dplyr)

dat.new <- dt %.%
  group_by(name) %.%
  mutate(dist = c(NA, end[-(length(end))] - start[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different dplyr solution:

```
dt %.% group_by(name) %.% mutate(dist = lag(end) - start)
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
Groups: name

  name   start     end    dist
1    1 3195984 3197398      NA
2    1 3203519 3205713   -6121
3    2 3204562 3207049      NA
4    2 3411782 3411982 -204733
5    2 3660632 3661579 -248650
6    3 3638391 3640590      NA
```